# Почему не работает событие onchange?

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка

К инпуту к событию  **onchange** нужно подключить регулярное выражение, чтобы вводились только цыфры, но почему не работает само событие **onchange**, в чем причина?

```
$('.test-input').onchange = function(){
    $(this).replace (/\D/g, '');
    console.log('*******');
};
```

Comment: `$(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '') );`

Comment: @Igor, заменил, как Вы написали, но почему console.log при вводе информации в инпут, ничего не показывает?

Comment: потому что событие `change` вызывается, когда фокус уходит с инпута

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('.test-input').addEventListener("input", function(){
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  console.log('***', this.value, '***');
});
```